# Not getting muliple instances of multithreaded datastream

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, object, stream

I am using a data generator which uses ports for streaming data. I use multiple ports mfor receiving data. The software I am writing makes a new socket for each port. Every socket should make an instance of a class called 'Interpreter'.

The problem I have is the following: I am able to make multiple instances of Interpreter, but I think the data is all being parsed to only one of the instances. I think this happens because the data is 'merged' in the output.

This is the most important snipet of the code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Socket socket;
        ServerSocket serverSocket=null;
        System.out.println("Server Listening..");
        try{
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7789);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        while(true){
            try{
                socket= serverSocket.accept();
                Interpreter interp = new Interpreter();
                ServerThread serverThr=new ServerThread(socket, interp);
                serverThr.start();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Connection Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
class ServerThread extends Thread {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader is = null;
    PrintWriter os = null;
    Socket s = null;

    public ServerThread(Socket s, Interpreter interp) {
        this.interp = interp;
        this.s = s;
        System.out.println("interp "+interp);
        System.out.println("s: "+s);
        System.out.println("poort: "+s.getPort());
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            os = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error in server thread");
        }

        try {
            line = is.readLine();
            while (line.compareTo("QUIT") != 0) {
                os.println(line);
                os.flush();
                Interpreter.interpreter(line);
                line = is.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            line = this.getName();
            System.out.println("IO Error/ Client " + line + " terminated abruptly");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            line = this.getName();
            System.out.println("Client " + line + " Closed");
        } finally {
            try {
                System.out.println("Connection Closing..");
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                    System.out.println(" Socket Input Stream Closed");
                }
                if (os != null) {
                    os.close();
                    System.out.println("Socket Out Closed");
                }
                if (s != null) {
                    s.close();
                    System.out.println("Socket Closed");
                }
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                System.out.println("Socket Close Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the 'important' part of Interpreter:

```
public class Interpreter{
    static AtomicInteger nextId = new AtomicInteger();
    int id = nextId.incrementAndGet();

    public Interpreter(){
        System.out.println("ID of demo "+id);
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.interp = interp;`
I don't see where `this.interp` is defined. You've got `line`,`is`,`os` and `s`, but I don't see `interp`

Comment: And where is 'demo' defined?

Comment: @WillD oh right, demo should not be in the code. this.interp is stated in ServerThread; should it not be there?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. There is no interp instance variable declared in ServerThread, so you can't set it in your constructor.

This may be why you always get the same thing. The interpreters you create and pass don't get stored.

                                Side note: This is why I always name the param differently from the attrib/instance variable, it prevents mistyping and mistaken identity. Basically, I hate **this** and use it as seldom as possible. ` void foo(String b) { bar = b;}` (when bar is an attrib) is pretty obvious IMO.

Comment: `Interpreter.interpreter(line);` There's no static method in Interpreter with this signature.

Comment: I think this assignment thing is your problem. Your debug out works correctly, because the new interp is in scope, but its collected almost immediately after that; no one else can ever see it.